# Taking a Screenshot inside CGRect returns blank/distorted image

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, core-graphics, screenshot

So I am building a meme app that lets you create your own memes by changing the text of two labels.

**General Layout**

[image: General Layout of the app]
The app consists of an ImageView across the whole scene with contentMode `aspectFit`. So some pictures are resized when picked.

**Taking a screenshot with blank spaces above and below**

When I take a screenshot of the image via the following code I get the correct result. However, the resulting image has blank spaces above and below.

```
private func generateMemedImage() -> UIImage {
    //self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    //        toolBar.isHidden = true

    // Render view to an image
    // Parameter 0.0 is required, so the generated image is not blurry.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.frame.size, false, 0.0)
    view.drawHierarchy(in: view.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    var memedImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    //self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
    //toolBar.isHidden = false

    return memedImage
}
```

**Result with above code**

[image]
So to automatically position the labels I have introduced a rectangle `containingImageHelperView`(illustrated in red below) which is basically a view that is added on top of all other views. (In reality the view is transparent)

[image]
Now I want to take a screenshot of only the red area.

```
private func generateMemedImage() -> UIImage {
    //self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    //        toolBar.isHidden = true

    // Render view to an image
    // Parameter 0.0 is required, so the generated image is not blurry.
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(containingImageHelperView!.frame.size, false, 0.0)
    view.drawHierarchy(in: containingImageHelperView!.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    var memedImage:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    //self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
    //toolBar.isHidden = false

    return memedImage
}
```

However, I get weird results. On emulator I just get a blank (white) picture and on a real device I get something like this (the red circle was only added for privacy purposes):

[image]
Notice, that the resulting screenshots have the correct size. But they do not show the contents as expected.

I hope I was clear enough. Please help!

If it helps to understand the whole project clearer, you can take a look at it here: https://github.com/Shanakor/MemeMe

Comment: You should post code instead of images , You need screenshot of  fullscreen but should contain image part ?

Comment: Uh sorry for the images, I will change them to actual code. 

I need a screenshot of the actual image part (the area under the containingImageHelperView) instead of the whole screen.

The ImageView is as big as the whole screen, but because of its contentMode the actual displayed image is smaller. That is why I even have the containingImageHelperView.